# Passing argument to a function in a query ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a function in my query in Access 2007 as following:

```
Function_Name('Query_1,'Field_1', Value_1, _
            'Date_Month=#' & [Date_Month] & '# and Code="' & [Code] & '"')
```

The function gives an error because of  the last argument: `'Date_Month=#' & [Date_Month] & '# and Code="' & [Code] & '"'`.
Is there anything wrong with the code of the last argument?? Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you've got your quotes messed up. It's not clear from your question whether you are calling or trying to declare a function, so I assume you are trying to call the function. In VBA, you need to use double quotes, and in the Access query, you should single quotes for strings.

```
Function_Name(Query_1, Field_1, Value_1, "Date_Month=#" & _
    [Date_Month] & "# and Code='" & [Code] & "'")
```

However, it is unclear exactly what the different parameters are referencing (variable names?), or why the fourth parameter is a string with the Date_Month and Code WHERE clause passed in.

Note, when you are searching for a date, it is #date# syntax, not #'date'#.

For example:

```
"Date_Month=#" & [Date_Month] & "#"
```

Comment: For clarification, i am calling a function from inside a query in Access.

Comment: S/he wasn't trying to use `#'date'#`, that was an artifact of getting the quoting style (`'` vs `"`) backwards.